# Stata - how to replicate single value for panel data?

Tags: stata

I have values of the net assets for 100 funds (it's one value of total net assets per fund). In Stata, I have the returns for each of those 100 funds for 200 months each stacked on top of each other (for panel data). How do I replicate each of the 100 net asset values times 200, and stack them up together - is there a method in Stata to do it?

Normally my process would be to create 100 columns in Excel and each column would have 200 rows of net assets (so if fund1 net assets are e.g. 1500000, I would copy this value into each of the 200 cells in a fund1 column). Then I would copy all of it to Stata and use 'stack' command to stack them up. It is very laborious and I want to avoid it in future if Stata offers a method that doesn’t involve Excel to this extent.

This is the data and essentially and I need each net asset value to be copied 200 times and stacked. So, you can imagine 9578780 stacked 200 times (same value) and then below another one 4695101 stacked 200 times under 9578780 and so on.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a small data example?

Comment: Added @JR96 thx

Comment: Sounds like a problem for the merge command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you want the `expand` command:

```
clear
input fund_id net_assets_share
1  9578780 
2 4695101 
end

expand 200
sort fund_id
```